# Delaunay triangulation with gradient fill?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uikit

I'm trying to recreate something like this shape - 
http://www.creativeapplications.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/horizon_02_1024x768.png - using UIKit or CoreGraphics on iOS.

The one in the picture was done with openFrameworks and it does run on iOS. However, I'd like to build the same without having to use oF, so I can keep it all native.

I assume the shape was created through Delaunay triangulation, which I can sort of do in Objective-C. The problem is filling the shapes with a gradient instead of a normal UIColor!

**Is there a way something like this could be done natively** with good performance on an iPad, or should I just do it with openFrameworks and bring that into the app as a layer?

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted a couple of times, so here is a +1 to make you even again.

Comment: Thanks Michael, appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to fill a triangle with a gradient? The following code does just that. To get it to work you need to add the QuartzCore framework, and

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

The code creates a shape layer in the shape of a triangle, and then uses this as a mask to a gradient layer. Hope this helps.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat w = self.bounds.size.width / 4;
    CGFloat h = self.bounds.size.height / 4;
    CGFloat x = w * 2;
    CGFloat y = h;
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path,NULL, x, y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, x+w, y+2*h);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, x-w, y+2*h);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);


    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    [shapeLayer setPath:path];

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.25, 1.0);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.75, 0.0);
    UIColor *startColour = [UIColor redColor];
    UIColor *endColour = [UIColor greenColor];
    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColour CGColor], (id)[endColour CGColor], nil];

    [gradientLayer setMask:shapeLayer];

    [self.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];

    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael. I want to know how to fill multiple triangles with different gradient fills, considering they probably all share a view/context

Comment: Doesn't it sound like you therefore need an array of gradient layers, each being a single triangle, and each with its own mask? The hardest part would be working out which goes on top of which.

Comment: If that's possible within the same context, this layering approach might be what i need! Especially since they'd never overlap! Will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to do a single triangle, but you can do multiple using repetition:

```
//Create the triangle Path and clip the drawing to it
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width * .4, self.bounds.size.height * 1/6.);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,self.bounds.size.width * .4, self.bounds.size.height * 3/6.);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,self.bounds.size.width * .2, self.bounds.size.height * 3/6.);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextClip(context);

//Now call the linear gradient drawing function
[self drawLinearGradient:context withRect:self.bounds startColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:.3] endColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:.3] startFraction:.3 stopFraction:1];

//And now restore so that we can clip the next triangle
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Now for the linear gradient drawing code:

```
- (void) drawLinearGradient: (CGContextRef) context withRect: (CGRect) rect startColor: (UIColor*) startColor endColor: (UIColor*)  endColor startFraction:(float)start stopFraction:(float)stop
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat locations[] = { start, stop };

    CGGradientRef myGradient;
    CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGColorRef startColorRef = [startColor CGColor];
    CGColorRef endColorRef = [endColor CGColor];

    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(startColorRef);
    CGFloat red     = components[0];
    CGFloat green = components[1];
    CGFloat blue   = components[2];
    CGFloat alpha = components[3];

    const CGFloat *components2 = CGColorGetComponents(endColorRef);
    CGFloat red2     = components2[0];
    CGFloat green2 = components2[1];
    CGFloat blue2   = components2[2];
    CGFloat alpha2 = components2[3];

    CGFloat colors[] =
    {
        red, green, blue, alpha,
        red2, green2, blue2, alpha2
    };

    myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgb, colors, locations, 2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, myGradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGGradientRelease(myGradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

You can setup this linear gradient function to handle more than two locations/colors if you would like.  This is very basic, but if you know the start and stop colors and locations of every triangle you should be able to accomplish what you want (drawing natively) using this code (without hundreds of sublayers).  Although the layers may draw faster, I have no idea.